# How to handle MixedQuery with CQRS?

Tags: architecture, cqrs, event-sourcing

In properly deisgned application it might be that you can separate all requests to commands (that only update aggregates and return void) and queries (that extract data from specific read optimized model).

But if you already have a heavy application and want to slowly move it to ES + CQRS path you might have requests that both modify and update models and return all the result (almost the same if you did a command and then query but that would be 2 requests) this is what i mean by mixed query.

I understand that this is clearly teoretical question and i dont have any code here to demonstrate it, but

**how do you handle such a request with CQRS?**

Comment: How is that, even slightly, closer to CQRS than what you did previously ?

Comment: Its not, but what i do is devide it into smaller projects, small independent modules and right now i want to refactor/redesign it with CQRS quite a lot of stuff to do. But right now i'm having some problems understanding if it can handle what i want to use it for... before actually migrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're basically talking about sacrificing [Command-Query Separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation), which is a prerequisite to CQRS and an all-time good development practice anyway.

If I were to move to a CQRS approach, I'd *start* by conforming to CQS if anything, separating queries from commands just at a method level, before bringing in the whole CQRS apparatus.

You don't have to do it as a big bang rework, you can go functional slice by functional slice, making sure you have high-level automated tests to secure the refactorings.

Comment: ok just forget about big project, say i'm writing from scratch, and my imaginary system have feature to create a new user... how do you do that with properly deisnged CQRS app?

Comment: just describe abstractly, for example does client send one command and immidiately a query after it? or is there something else?

I cant move forward as most of the use cases in real world i can see are indeed mixed queries...

Comment: i can perfectly see how good it will perform if my only backend is initiating any update to user but its not always the case...

Comment: You might want to edit your question or ask another one, since it doesn't seem to reflect you real needs (refreshing the UI just after sending a command, as far as I can tell).

Comment: This should help you though : http://danielwhittaker.me/2014/10/27/4-ways-handle-eventual-consistency-ui/# https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dddcqrs/Pwow6c0cqec

Answer (score 3):

Your "mixed query" is out of scope for CQRS. My answer would be - if you have this, you do not have CQRS. CQRS means commands and queries are *segregated*, this is the whole point.

You do not have to move everything to the new model immediately, you will have two parallel systems and move from one to another piece by piece. I would strongly not recommend mixing old stuff into the new model.

Comment: For example a simple request from an application that wants to create a new user, it at least shall get some idea if the whole thing gone ok or it failed... 

What is the proper way to do that behaviour with CQRS? i think this is a very common example...

Comment: I could think of solution that if you had a ful duplex communication with client like websocket then after updating read model it could send update to user but i dont think it is the case with most applications...

Comment: The command can fail with an exception, this will be a good indication if your command has completed or not. In CQS commands do not return anything, i.e. state mutation methods are always void. It is possible to build fluent interfaces when your command returns the actual aggregate, it is fine too. But CQRS "splits one object into two" so write model should not be querying anything from the read model and surely should not return any query results.

Comment: How do you handle this "traditional" case then without AJAX or a SPA like frontend: Have a controller or request handler (we're in a web context) and we want to render a form with a list, the list obviously needs a query. Now we do a post, the answer, if the form data was invalid should contain the list data to populate the list input. So I would have to do a query and command in the same  handler?